# Trouble creating zip file in Firebase Cloud Function

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to create a zip file of a string in a Firebase Cloud Function. I have a load of documents in a Firestore collection and each document has a sub collection of documents too.I am trying to iterate through the documents constructing the String (which will be a csv file) and then output in a zipped file. Unfortunately when I initiate the function to create the zip file it exits early out of the function delivering a zipped file not containing the relevant information. Just the initial headers that are in the csv file.

Firebase cloud function code is as follows:

```js
    newApp.get('/createUtilCSV', (req, res) => {
        try {
            console.log("CreateAuditCSV started");
            const tempFilePath = path.join(os.tmpdir(), "Util_" + req.query.start + "---" + req.query.end + ".csv");
            console.log("Temp File Path: " + tempFilePath);
            let docRef = firestore.collection('utilisation');
            console.log("DocRef:" + docRef);
            var fromD = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(req.query.start));
            var toD = admin.firestore.Timestamp.fromDate(new Date(req.query.end));
            console.log("from date: ", fromD);
            console.log("to date: ", toD);
            docRef.where("timestamp", ">=", fromD).where("timestamp", "<=", toD).get().then(snapshot => {
                var output = fs.createWriteStream(tempFilePath);
                var archive = archiver('zip', {
                    gzip: true,
                    zlib: {
                        level: 9
                    } // Sets the compression level.
                });
                console.log("Snapshot:" + snapshot.size);
                var utilText = "App Version,Author,Building,City,Country,Date,Floor ID,Floor Name, Floor Region,Bookable,Business Unit,Capacity,Fixed,Furniture Height,Occupancy,Position X,Position Y,Restricted,Status Date,Status Type,Unique Ref,Workspace Type,Report ID\n";
                let utils = snapshot.docs;
                console.log("Snapshot count:" + snapshot.capacity);
                utils.forEach(doc => {
                    var line = doc.data();
                    var utilLine = "";
                    utilLine = utilLine + line.appVersion + ",";
                    utilLine = utilLine + line.authorEmail + ",";
                    utilLine = utilLine + line.building + ",";
                    utilLine = utilLine + line.city + ",";
                    utilLine = utilLine + line.country + ",";
                    utilLine = utilLine + line.timestamp.toDate() + ",";
                    utilLine = utilLine + line.floorId + ",";
                    utilLine = utilLine + line.floorName + ",";
                    utilLine = utilLine + line.region + ",";
                    var utilisationCollection = firestore.collection('utilisation').doc(line.documentID).collection('workspaces');
                    utilisationCollection.get().then(snap => {
                        let workspaces = snap.docs;
                        workspaces.forEach(space => {
                            var lineSpace = space.data();
                            var spaceAdd = utilLine;
                            spaceAdd = spaceAdd + lineSpace.bookable + ",";
                            spaceAdd = spaceAdd + lineSpace.businessUnit + ",";
                            spaceAdd = spaceAdd + lineSpace.capacity + ",";
                            spaceAdd = spaceAdd + lineSpace.fixed + ",";
                            spaceAdd = spaceAdd + lineSpace.height + ",";
                            spaceAdd = spaceAdd + lineSpace.occupancy + ",";
                            spaceAdd = spaceAdd + lineSpace.positionX + ",";
                            spaceAdd = spaceAdd + lineSpace.positionY + ",";
                            spaceAdd = spaceAdd + lineSpace.restricted + ",";
                            spaceAdd = spaceAdd + lineSpace.statusDate.toDate() + ",";
                            spaceAdd = spaceAdd + lineSpace.statusType + ",";
                            spaceAdd = spaceAdd + lineSpace.uniqueRef + ",";
                            spaceAdd = spaceAdd + lineSpace.workspaceType + ",";
                            spaceAdd = spaceAdd + line.documentID + "\n";
                            console.log("SpaceAdd: " + spaceAdd);
                            utilText = utilText + spaceAdd;
                        });
                    });
                });
                try {
                    // listen for all archive data to be written
                    // 'close' event is fired only when a file descriptor is involved
                    output.on('close', function() {
                        console.log(archive.pointer() + ' total bytes');
                        console.log('archiver has been finalized and the output file descriptor has closed.');
                        console.log("Util Text: ", utilText);
                        bucket.upload(tempFilePath, {
                            make_public: true,
                            gzip: true,
                            destination: tempFilePath,
                            metadata: metadata,
                        });
                        //Let's get the signed URL
                        const file = admin.storage().bucket().file(tempFilePath);
                        console.log('File: ' + file);
                        var expiryDate = new Date();
                        expiryDate.setDate(expiryDate.getDate() + 1);
                        file.getSignedUrl({
                            action: 'read',
                            expires: expiryDate
                        }).then(urls => {
                            const signedUrl = urls[0];
                            console.log('Send: ' + signedUrl);
                            res.redirect(signedUrl);
                            res.end();
                        });
                    });
                    output.on('end', function() {
                        console.log('Data has been drained');
                    });
                    // good practice to catch warnings (ie stat failures and other non-blocking errors)
                    archive.on('warning', function(err) {
                        if(err.code === 'ENOENT') {
                            // log warning
                        } else {
                            // throw error
                            throw err;
                        }
                    });
                    // good practice to catch this error explicitly
                    archive.on('error', function(err) {
                        throw err;
                    });
                    const metadata = {
                        contentType: "application/zip",
                    };
                    archive.pipe(output);
                    // append a file from string
                    archive.append(utilText, {
                        name: tempFilePath
                    });
                    archive.finalize();
                    console.log("tempFilePath: " + tempFilePath);
                    console.log("Export Util CSV finished");
                } catch(err) {
                    console.log(err);
                }
            }).catch(err => console.log(err));
        } catch(error) {
            console.log("Export error:" + error);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Is the [Export operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import#export_data) suitable for your need?

Comment: No Frank, I am needing to create a very specific csv file and as far as I know the Export operation won't quite do that.

Comment: The export from gcloud can be `--collection-ids` flag, which you can use to select the collections being exported, can you mention if the csv limitation is due to the headers, or is there any other limitation you have for it?